# Delete git master branch in redmine

Tags: git

I have a redmine repository using git and want to delete the master branch in the remote repo. However, I get this error message: [image]

Does anyone know why I get the message and can tell me how I still delete the branch?

Comment: I think it is because a branch cannot be deleted if you have checked out that branch. May be checkout another branch, and then delete master branch. But I doubt that master branch is the main branch, it might not be possible to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

This error actually has nothing to do with what branch *you* are currently on. Rather, it is the *server* that is throwing the error. My guess is that it is throwing this error for one of two reasons: either it is not a bare repository, and its current branch really is `master` (though I doubt it, as then you would get errors pushing any changes to master), or its default branch is `master` (i.e. `origin/HEAD` points to `master`).

If you have control over the server, configure it so that it has a different default branch. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've created another branch 'placeholder' for testing. After I switched to master branch, I was allowed to delete the placeholder branch successfully. But is there no other opportunity to delete the master branch or clean it or sth else? [image]